# Set `-R` raw data option inside jq script

Tags: jq

we are trying to write a generic data processor in a bash script that uses `jq` for part of the processing. A `jq` script file is passed to the script as a configuration option and this is the only thing we want to forward to `jq` other than the piped input.

We would like to be able to process both `csv` and `json` as input data, and have the logic entirely contained in the `jq` script. However, for `csv` parsing we need to set the `-R` option, which is set outside of the script (as a command-line argument).

Is it possible to somehow set the `-R` option within a `jq` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to somehow set the -R option within a jq script?

No.

However, there are a couple of workarounds, as illustrated below.  These assume that the first line of the CSV file is not valid JSON. Using the second technique, the loss in efficiency should be minimal apart from the costs associated with reading the entire file into memory unconditionally.

#### Using `fromjson`

In this case, once a determination has been made that the input is not JSON, a switch is made to CSV-processing mode.

Example

```
jq -Rs '. as $in
  | try fromjson 
    catch ($in | splits("\n") | split(",") | select(length>0))'
```

### Using --rawfile and `inputs`

The idea is to read from `inputs` if possible, and otherwise switch to reading from the file specified by --rawfile.

Example

```
< inputfile jq -n --rawfile raw inputfile '
  def handleCSV: $raw | splits("\n") | split(",") | select(length>0);
  try inputs catch handleCSV
'
```

Comment: If the second technique is used, the performance impact should be quite small but note that --rawfile will read the entire file into memory unconditionally.  If the first technique is used, the performance impact would depend on various factors.